# How can I call .aspx page in div tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to load the .aspx page in some portion of existing page (in div tag) using javascript.
When I click on link on my page at that time I want to do above thing.
Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? We're here to help resolve problems, not to provide you with complete solutions.

Comment: I don't want complete solution. I just want the trick to solve that problem. You know that in our field for one problem there are multiple solutions. So it will be helpful to increase knowledge related to that. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (or one of the many [jQuery AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)) will do the trick.